# Cannot View Users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Assuming this is on the way, but having not seen it previously reported: I can't view myself from the sidebar, or anyone else by tapping them.

## View Self From Sidebar:

[image]

---

## View Asker/Answerer:

[image]

---

## View Commenter:

[image]

Comment: My mistake, I checked the dates but closed the opposite one. Let me rectify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done for a while.  All those places (plus links to users) take you to the network profile.

Comment: It sure has! If any particular field is still missing, that can be a new feature request. Put this one to bed!

Answer (score 2):

This feature will be implemented during the beta phase of our app. I can't make any promises as to when exactly it will be completed. However, since this feature exists on our Android app, we will definitely be implementing it here as well.