# Add a link to the profile in the left sidebar

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, ios-app

On the left sidebar, the first item of the menu is my profile pic + nickname. It seems to be a fake link. Wouldn't be cool if this link goes to my profile instead of doing nothing?

Or maybe, instead of a "non-link", display a summary of my profile (points, number of badges, profile views, helpful tags, etc..).

[image: profile link]

Comment: Related: [Cannot View Users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220427) (but the latter part of your suggestion is a bit different)

Comment: Clearly that tap target should do more - I wonder what the best use case will end up doing.