# How do I get to my profile on the iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app

I tried clicking on my profile user/picture but nothing happens.

How do I view my profile on the app?

Comment: What app? your profile in SE is accessible as long as  you have internet connection. I am missing something, so better detail it

Comment: The iOS app. I cannot seem to figure out how to see my profile or anyone else's

Comment: Not entirely a link @timstone

Comment: The more general one is [Cannot View Users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220427), but it was closed as a duplicate of the above question.

Comment: Hmmm I cannot seem to edit it delete a comment in the app either

Comment: Yep, this falls into the other two questions.  Definitely on our todo list.